# Pass more values when using Jeditable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable in conjunction with datatables to create/edit a dynamic table, which in turn updates the SQL database.

At the present time, by default, Jeditable passes "id" and "value" to my PHP file. I was wondering if there's any way I can also get it to pass the column header from the table?

I'm currently using this:

```
$('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( 'manage.php', {
                    "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
                        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                        oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
                    },
                    "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                        return {
                            "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                            "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]

                        };
                    },
                    "height": "14px"
            });
```

I also want to move the previous/next page from below the table to above the table. I've been trying to understand the sDom input with Datatables, however I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Why do you need it - pass the column header?

Comment: At the minute, it passes the id of the row, and the edited cell data. I need to know what column the cell is in, in order to update the SQL database correctly.

Comment: You have to know that each Jeditable submit action sends information about ONE field, not a row of fields (you can't submit data from whole row of fields simultaneously). If you want to use Jeditable on multiple columns you have to call Jeditable for fields of each column, assigning separate server script to handle data from appropriate column's fields.

Comment: Well at the minute it passes the id of the row and the new cell value, I need to be able to pass what column it was in (or figure out another way to find out which it was)

Comment: However you may use one server-side handling script receiving information about column through GET parameter.

Answer (score 0):

simply accept columnName like this
$columnname=$_POST["columnName"];
you will get column name so u can update table by knowing colunm name

Answer (score 0):

```
submitdata: function (value, settings) {
    return {
        "id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
        "column": bTable.fnGetPosition(this)[2],
        "col_name": bTable.fnSettings().aoHeader[0][bTable.fnGetPosition(this)[2]].cell.attributes['id'].nodeValue
    };
}
```

I set the ID property of the column with the data field name (inside the HTML markup) since the column display name I want to show to the user is different for me. You can dig up the column display name this way too.